# Adding codeowners for files in the root directory only

Tags: github, code-organization

If I have a project structured like this:

```
project
│   README.md
│   config.json
    package.json
│
└───folder1
│   │   fileA.js
│   │   fileB.html
│   
└───folder2
    │   fileC.js
    │   fileD.html
```

How can I add a rule to the `CODEOWNERS` file that gives a user ownership of only the files in the root folder, but not the files in any of the subdirectories?

I've tried the following but none of them seem to work the way I want:

```
# CODEOWNERS
/ @johnSmith

./ @johnSmith

/* @johnSmith
```

Comment: Based on [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners), it would seem that you can't do that. (Note specifically that there's no negation directive.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some experimenting this seems to work:

```
#CODEOWNERS

/*.* @userName

/apps @differentUserName
```

That will give `@userName` ownership of root files. It also applies to files inside dot-prefix folders, like `.github/` or `.vscode/` but no other nested directories

Comment: Am I correct, this will not work for files that do not have an extension, such as _CODEOWNERS_?